# Polynomial rings which are Dedekind domains.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $K$ be a field. Is $K[X,Y]$ a Dedekind domain?

Comment: Please include what you have tried to prove of disprove the statement. That way, you will get more answers that fit your experience level or suitable hints that will help you more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because a Dedekind domain is an integrally closed noetherian domain (this is true for $K[X,Y]$) of Krull dimension $1$, and $\dim K[X,Y]=2$.

$K[X,Y]$  is integrally closed, because a polynomial ring over an integrally closed domain is itself integrally closed.

As for the assertion about the dimension, the general fact is that for any $K$-algebra of finite type $A$ which is an integral domain with fraction field $L$, we have
$$\dim A=\operatorname{deg\,tr} L $$
(*Bourbaki, Algebra*, Ch. 8 ‘Dimension’, § 2, n°4, theorem 3).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? Why does $K[X,Y]$ have Krull dimension 2? 

In general, why does $K[x_1,x_2....x_n]$, where $K$ is a field, have dimension $n$?

Also, why is $K[X,Y]$ integrally closed?

Comment: @J.G.: I added some details.